# Why am i getting an invalid datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Probably a simple question but I cannot see where i have made a mistake, i'm new to oracle and appreciate any help.

The code I have done to get the error is below;

```
CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    BugID varchar(5),
    BugType varchar(10),
    BugTime time,
    BugDesc varchar(10),
    primary key(BugID)
)
```

I have a suspicion its the time datatype that is causing this error but again i am not sure why.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483), there is no time data type in Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of time use timestamp-

Here is the documentation-

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm

Answer (score 3):

There is no `time` datatype in Oracle. You probably want `date` instead, which can be used to store date and time:

```
CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    BugID varchar2(5),
    BugType varchar2(10),
    BugTime date,
    BugDesc varchar2(10),
    primary key(BugID)
)
```

Also, you want to use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`, which is being deprecated by Oracle.

Comment: ok thank you very much for the help, yes have realised i needed to use varchar2 instead thanks!

Comment: `varchar` isn't deprecated. It's currently simply replaced by `varchar2` when running the CREATE TABLE statement. But Oracle states that the behaviour of such a column with regards to empty strings might change in the future (but only for tables created _then_, not for existing tables)